# Xilinx ISE warns that a signal is trimmed since it has a constant value of 0, but the signal is used within my code

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I have created the following VHDL module, which is used as an up/down counter.

```
entity counter is
Port(clk        : in  STD_LOGIC;
     count_clk  : in  STD_LOGIC;
     reset      : in  STD_LOGIC;
     count_up   : in  STD_LOGIC;
     count_down : in  STD_LOGIC;
     counting   : out STD_LOGIC;
     value      : out signed(19 downto 0));
end counter;

architecture Behavioral of counter is
    signal temp_value   : signed(19 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal last_clk_val : STD_LOGIC           := '0';
begin
process(clk, reset)
begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        temp_value <= (others => '0');
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (last_clk_val = '0' and count_clk = '1') then
            if (count_up = '1') then
                temp_value <= temp_value + 1;
            elsif (count_down = '1') then
                temp_value <= temp_value - 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
last_clk_val <= count_clk;
counting     <= count_up or count_down;
value        <= temp_value;
end Behavioral;
```

ISE presents me with the following warning (for each bit of temp_value):

```
WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <ttl_top_inst/COUNTER_COMPONENT/temp_value_0> has a constant value of 0 in block <ttl_oneshot_inputs_top>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

Adding the Following lines to the code marked with --ADDED LINES removes the warning, but temp_value should not be altered at that point of the code.

```
entity counter is
Port(clk        : in  STD_LOGIC;
     count_clk  : in  STD_LOGIC;
     reset      : in  STD_LOGIC;
     count_up   : in  STD_LOGIC;
     count_down : in  STD_LOGIC;
     counting   : out STD_LOGIC;
     value      : out signed(19 downto 0));
end counter;

architecture Behavioral of counter is
    signal temp_value   : signed(19 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal last_clk_val : STD_LOGIC           := '0';
begin
process(clk, reset)
begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        temp_value <= (others => '0');
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (last_clk_val = '0' and count_clk = '1') then
            if (count_up = '1') then
                temp_value <= temp_value + 1;
            elsif (count_down = '1') then
                temp_value <= temp_value - 1;
            end if;
        else --ADDED LINES
            temp_value <= temp_value - 1; --ADDED LINES
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
last_clk_val <= count_clk;
counting     <= count_up or count_down;
value        <= temp_value;
end Behavioral;
```

The code works without problems in the simulation, but I know that the simulation does not equal the actual implementation.

Could someone give me directions on how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this line:

```
last_clk_val <= count_clk;
```

is outside of the clocked process, both signals will have the same value in hardware (and also in simulation after a delta-cycle<sup>1</sup>). Thus, this condition within your process

```
if (last_clk_val = '0' and count_clk = '1') then
```

will never be true and the process will be equivalent to:

```
process(clk, reset)
begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        temp_value <= (others => '0');
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        null;
    end if;
end process;
```

Together with the signal initialization, this gives a constant value of all '0' for `temp_value`.

If you want to delay `count_clk` for one cycle to detect a rising-edge on this signal, you have to move the assignment of `last_clk_val` inside the process:

```
process(clk, reset)
begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        temp_value <= (others => '0');
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (last_clk_val = '0' and count_clk = '1') then
            if (count_up = '1') then
                temp_value <= temp_value + 1;
            elsif (count_down = '1') then
                temp_value <= temp_value - 1;
            end if;

        last_clk_val <= count_clk;  -- moved here
    end if;
end process;
```

---

In simulation, all signal assignment are delayed. If no delay is given, then the signal assignment is delayed by a delta-cycle. Thus, if `count_clk` changes then `count_clk` will differ from `last_clk_val` for one delta-cycle in the original code. In hardware both signals are represented by the same wire.